# How to use INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P in header file with multiple test .cpps?

Tags: c++, googletest

Say I have a GTest fixture defined in a header file fixtures.h:

```
 class baseFixture : public ::testing::Test{
   // some shared functionality among tests
 }
```

As well as a derived fixture that allows for some parameterization:

```
class derivedFixture: public baseFixture, 
  public ::testing::WithParamInterface<std::tuple<bool, int>>{};
```

That I would like to use along with INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P in order to parameterize a large set of tests that are distributed among N .cpp files. I would like to write in the header:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(derivedTests, derivedFixture, 
  ::testing::Combine(::testing::Bool(), ::testing::Values(1));
```

In order to run the set of tests for the cross product of {true, false} and {1}. When I compile just one cpp file, call it N1.cpp, and run the executable, I get the correct behavior with my `TEST_P(derivedFixture*` tests- they run twice each. However, when I build the whole project and execute my tests, each test is run 2 * N times. I have used include guards in the header file to prevent the INSTANTIATE macro from being invoked twice, and am positive I do not invoke it anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially this:

**fixture.hpp (1)**

```
#ifndef FIXTURE_HPP
#define FIXTURE_HPP

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct fixture: ::testing::TestWithParam<std::tuple<bool, int>>
{};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(instantiation_one, fixture,
  ::testing::Combine(::testing::Bool(), ::testing::Values(1)));

#endif
```

**t1.cpp**

```
#include "fixture.hpp"
#include <tuple>

TEST_P(fixture, test_a)
{
    auto const & param = GetParam();
    std::cout << "param 0 = " << std::get<0>(param) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "param 1 = " << std::get<1>(param) << std::endl;
    SUCCEED();
}
```

**t2.cpp**

```
#include "fixture.hpp"
#include <tuple>

TEST_P(fixture, test_b)
{
    auto const & param = GetParam();
    std::cout << "param 0 = " << std::get<0>(param) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "param 1 = " << std::get<1>(param) << std::endl;
    SUCCEED();
}
```

**main.cpp (1)**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile, link and run:

```
$ ./gtester
[==========] Running 8 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 8 tests from instantiation_one/fixture
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/0
param 0 = 0
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/1
param 0 = 1
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/0
param 0 = 0
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/1
param 0 = 1
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/0
param 0 = 0
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/1
param 0 = 1
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/0
param 0 = 0
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/1
param 0 = 1
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/1 (0 ms)
[----------] 8 tests from instantiation_one/fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 8 tests from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 8 tests.
```

You see 8 tests when you expected 4, with each `instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/N` being run twice, for `N` in {0,1}.

The bug is this: We do:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(instantiation_one, fixture,
  ::testing::Combine(::testing::Bool(), ::testing::Values(1)));
```

in `fixture.hpp`, which is `#include`-ed, and therefore repeated, in *every
translation unit* `tN.cpp`, causing the 2 parameterised tests that are registered
by this code to be registered `N` times at runtime, and hence run N times.

We are supposed to compile each instantiation of a value-parameterized fixture
for a given set of values just *once*, so do it in only *one* source file, e.g.

**fixture.hpp (2)**

```
#ifndef FIXTURE_HPP
#define FIXTURE_HPP

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct fixture: ::testing::TestWithParam<std::tuple<bool, int>>
{};


#endif
```

**main.cpp (2)**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "fixture.hpp"

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(instantiation_one, fixture,
  ::testing::Combine(::testing::Bool(), ::testing::Values(1)));

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Recompile, relink and rerun:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -c main.cpp t1.cpp t2.cpp
$ g++ -o gtester main.o t1.o t2.o -lgtest -pthread
$ ./gtester
[==========] Running 4 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 4 tests from instantiation_one/fixture
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/0
param 0 = 0
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/1
param 0 = 1
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_a/1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/0
param 0 = 0
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/0 (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/1
param 0 = 1
param 1 = 1
[       OK ] instantiation_one/fixture.test_b/1 (0 ms)
[----------] 4 tests from instantiation_one/fixture (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 4 tests from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 4 tests.
```

Comment: Maybe I have a misunderstanding of translation units. I thought the #ifndef guards in fixture.hpp would cause the macro to only be run once. Since this is not the case, why is it run multiple times?

Comment: @PhilipDakin Hi. Header guards stop the contents of `foo.h` being preprocessed and
compiled more than once in a [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) no matter how many times it
`#include`s `foo.h`. If you compile *N* translation units that each `#include
foo.h` and successfully link the *N* object files into a program, then any code generated
in an object file as a result of compiling the contents of `foo.h` will be
linked into the program *N* times.